# 'New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule' is not recognized - Azure PowerShell Issue with Azure Dev Ops Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to run a SQL Script with the pipeline in a Automated Deployment for DB changes with below YML file. But i get error saying below.

Tutorial I follow is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```
trigger:
 - main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2022

variables:
  AzureSubscription: 'XXX'
  ResourceGroupName: 'XXX'
  ResourceDBGroupName: 'XXX'
  ServerName: 'XXX'
  DatabaseName: 'XXX'
  AdminUser: 'XXX'
  AdminPassword: 'XXX'
  SQLFile: 'DatabasePipelineTest/scripts/script.sql'
  AzureFirewallName: 'allow-pipe'

steps:
- script: dir
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script to test'

- task: AzurePowerShell@2
  displayName: Azure PowerShell
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    ScriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DatabasePipelineTest/scripts/SetAzureFirewallRule.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-ServerName $(ServerName) -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceDBGroupName) -AzureFirewallName $(AzureFirewallName)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

- task: CmdLine@1
  displayName: Run Sqlcmd
  inputs:
    filename: Sqlcmd
    arguments: '-S $(ServerName) -U $(AdminUser) -P $(AdminPassword) -d $(DatabaseName) -i $(SQLFile)'

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: Azure PowerShell
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    ScriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DatabasePipelineTest/scripts/RemoveAzureFirewallRule.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '$(ServerName)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Output I get in the Console is as below,

```
Azure PowerShell

View raw log
Starting: Azure PowerShell
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 2.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell
==============================================================================
Added TLS 1.2 in session.
Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\azurerm_6.13.1\AzureRM\6.13.1\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave -ErrorAction Stop
Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[error]The term 'New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Finishing: Azure PowerShell
```

The script that has the issue is below

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'None')]
param
(
  [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $ServerName,
  [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $ResourceGroupName,
  [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $AzureFirewallName
)
$agentIP = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("https://api.ipify.org")
New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -FirewallRuleName $AzureFirewallName -StartIPAddress $agentIp -EndIPAddress $agentIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the DevOps task if you have specified the task version: *4. (Preview)* or higher to use the Az powershell module

Comment: How do we check this? I only have verison 1.* and 2.* available for a 'powershell task'

Comment: @adudley have a look at this task potentially: AzurePowerShell@5 found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines